# How to get id of form attributes and add them to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, dotnetnuke

I am creating a dotnetnuke module, where i need to add some data to database, using LINQ to SQL

**I have one, default form which looks like this:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputValue" class="form-control" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="inputNumOfItems" type="number" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="inputDropdownList" class="form-control" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Value1" Value="Value1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Value2" Value="Value2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Value3" Value="Value3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Value4" Value="Value4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Value5" Value="Value5"></asp:ListItem>
```

**And i create another using webservice addnew.asmx, which looks like this:**

```
public string  getRandomID()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetHTMLizdelek()
    {

        string html = 
            @"
             <div class=""form-group"">
                  <div id=""accordion"">
                      <h3 class=""accordion-append"">Add new</h3>
                      <div class=""skrijDrugo"">
                          <input type=""text"" ID=""inputValue" + getRandomID() + @""" class=""form-control"" runat=""server""><br />
                          <input type=""number"" ID=""inputNumOfItems" + getRandomID() + @""" type=""number"" class=""form-control"" runat=""server""><br />
                          <select ID=""inputDropdownList" + getRandomID() + @""" class=""form-control"" runat=""server"">
                             <option value=""Value1"">Value1</option>
                             <option value=""Value1"">Value1</option>
                             <option value=""Value1"">Value1</option>
                             <option value=""Value1"">Value1</option>
                             <option value=""Value1"">Value1</option>
                          </select><br />
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div> 
             ";
        return html;
```

On button click i load form from my service, which creates form that has different id's, so i can add multiple data to database. (in case user wants do add more products than one)

Now i need to cycle through id's and put that data to database. I'm stuck here, i have absolutely no idea what to do.

Please help

**UPDATE**

tried this, but i dunno what to do next.

```
List<int> listValues = new List<int>();
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("input"))
            {
                listValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[key]));
            }

        }
```

Comment: why you are using random value. you can try sequential number and take data by using control name as you can always generate the control name again...

Comment: any examples? @Raghavendra

Comment: i don't have any example right now... you can search 
you can try with sequence number as well but may be you have to pass the number in webmethod to keep the sequence